# Gnuplot - greek letters - tau

Tags: gnuplot

How to write tau in gnuplot, please? What is wrong with this script?

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 1600,1000 font "Times New Roman,32" 
set output "graf.png"   
set title "{/Symbol t}"
f(x) = sin(x)
plot f(x)
```

I tried Arial and Segoe UI too.

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps your font does not have the character?

Comment: Which font do you use? 
I tried Arial and Segoe UI too. It didn't work as well.

Comment: Works for me too. `It didn't work` is vague. Please post the image what your code resulted in for you. What is `locale` in your environment?

Comment: I'm using Fedora Linux, and `Times New Roman` ends up as `Liberation Serif` with the rpm `liberation-serif-fonts` installed. Perhaps you can update the question with your OS and distribution.

Comment: Thank you I tried another computer and it worked.

Comment: Just a note: The issue is not any of Times New Roman/Liberation/Arial/whatever that is used as the default font. The issue is whether the installed font found by name "Symbol" is the Adobe-encoded symbol font or some other symbol font that is not in Adobe encoding.  Unless you need PostScript output, your best bet is to work in UTF-8 and not switch fonts: `set title "τ"`